# Rails: undefined method `has_liked?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a NoMethodError that I can't figure out, it's saying `undefined method 'has_liked?'`. I have an "ideas" crud that has "comments", and I'm trying to add the ability to like/dislike comments.

`NoMethodError in Comments#new` on this line here `<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_liked?(comment) %>`

Here's my comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @ideas = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @ideas = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    @comment = @ideas.comments.build(comment_params)
    # @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to new_idea_comment_path (@ideas)
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:id, :body)
  end

end
```

(comments) _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@ideas, @comment] do |f| %>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Submit comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Go back?", root_path %>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(comments) edit.html.erb

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

(comments) new.html.erb

```
<%= render "form" %>

<% for comment in @ideas.comments %>
  <div class="container">
      <%= comment.body %>

      <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_liked?(comment) %>
        <% like = current_user.likes.find_by_comment_id(comment.id) %>
        <%= link_to "unlike", comment_likes_path(comment, like), class: "btn btn-danger like  ", method: :delete %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "like", comment_like_path(comment), class: "btn btn-info like ", method: :post %>
      <% end %>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

likes_controller.rb

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    comment   = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
    like      = comment.likes.new
    like.user = current_user
    if like.save
      redirect_to new_idea_comment_path(comment.idea), notice: "Liked!"
    else
      redirect_to new_idea_comment_path(comment.idea), alert: "Already liked!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    comment = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
    like    = comment.likes.find params[:id]
    if like.destroy
      redirect_to new_idea_comment_path(comment.idea), notice: "Unliked!"
    else
      redirect_to new_idea_comment_path(comment.idea), alert: "Can't unlike!"
    end
  end

end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end
```

like.rb

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root "ideas#index"

  resources :ideas do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments, only: [] do
    resources :likes
  end
```

Comment: Can you provide information of line number and file in which exception is coming?

Comment: You don't have `.has_liked?` instance method in `User` class, why would it work?

Comment: @Nishu I updated my original post to include that.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I completely forgot about my user.rb, thank you I will see if this works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement something like this to use `.has_liked?` on users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes

  def has_liked?(comment)
    likes.where(comment_id: comment.id).present?
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks I did this and I think it solved that issue. Except I'm now getting an `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` error instead. It's saying `missing required keys: [:id]`  on this line of code here `<%= link_to "like", comment_like_path(comment), class: "btn btn-info like ", method: :post %>`. Any idea of what I should put there?